# Can we add Instamojo payments integration on shopify?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, shopify

Can we add Instamojo payments integration on shopify?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If instamojo has an API it can be made as a payment gateway...

Answer (score 1):

No shopify not allowed instamojo. You can refer below link to see which third party shopify allow:

https://www.shopify.in/payment-gateways/india

Comment: Thanks for replay. can we write custom code for this into shopify like php code?

Comment: I don't think so because shopify not allow that kind of behavior otherwise you can easily find extension for it :)

Comment: I could not find extension of instamojo. any other option?

Comment: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/how-can-we-add-php-page-in-shopify-343732 try with api but you before start get permission from shopify.

Comment: Yes, instamojo has an API. how we can made into shopify.